# How can I add several months to a date coming from a date form field?

Tags: date, field, addition, datejs

With DateJS, you'd add e.g. six months to the current date like this:

```
Date.today().addMonths(6);
```

However, I need to add 24 months not to today's date, but to a date which a user has typed into a date field. So the `today()` should in principle be replaced by something like `this.getField('begin_date').value`.

The result shall be written into another data form field.

I tried hard, but couldn't make it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the input value is a textual representation of a date, you need to convert it into a `Date` object at the first place. Then you can work with it as you want.

DateJS has a pretty smart [`parse()`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parse) function which does exactly that, so you'd achieve it like this:

```
Date.parse(this.getField('begin_date').value).addMonths(24)
```

When a specific date format is needed, like `DD.MM.YYYY` commonly used in Europe, you can use [`parseExact()`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) and specify the format. Like this:

```
Date.parseExact(dateToParse, 'dd.MM.yyyy')  // leading zeroes required; parses 01.04.2014 but not 1.4.2014
Date.parseExact(dateToParse, 'd.M.yyyy')  // leading zeroes not required; parses both 01.04.2014 and 1.4.2014
```

Comment: Thanks for this! In principle, it works fine, but the parse() function mixes up my days and month. My date fields are formatted like "dd.mm.yyyy", so that 01.04.2014 means "first of April, 2014". The parse() function, however, makes "January 4th, 2014", out of it. Do I have a chance to correct that?

Comment: I've tried: `var begin = this.getField('begin_date').value;`

`end = Date.parseExact(begin, 'dd.MM.yyyy');`  But I get "null" as result. Only if I enter eg:  `end = Date.parseExact('01.02.2015', 'dd.MM.yyyy');`  then I'll get the desired result.  What else could I do in order to have Date.parse() arranged my day and month correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the value of `begin` actually *is* a valid date?

Comment: At least, it seems so; app.alert shows me eg `1.10.2005` as value of `begin` (no hours, minutes, seconds etc.), meaning the first of October, 2015. But the value of `end` is still shown as `null`.
Is there maybe another way? The actual problem seems to be that `Date.parse()` assumes that `month` stands before `date`. Do I maybe have to create my own Date object out of my begin_date from field?
Thanks!

Comment: Well we are a bit off the original question now; however, see my update again. I'd recommend studying the documentation for DateJS thoroughly.

Comment: Obviously there is an issue in Date.parse() which I raised at the appropriate place. Date.parseExact won't work either under certain cirsumstances. So 1) thank you very much again for your help and b) look for alternatives if you have the same problem than I had.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I found for my problem, using DateJS as well:

```
start = this.getField('begin_date').value;
var d1 = util.scand("dd.mm.yyyy", start);
var myDate = new Date(d1);
result = myDate.addMonths(24);
```

This works pretty fine, also spanning leap years, except for the 28th of February, 2014/2018/2022 ... ; the result then will be the 28th of February, 2016/2020/2024 ... and not the 29th of February 2016/2020/2024... In these cases it's up to the user to accept the 28th or to manually change the date to the 29th.